# Formula to select a range in a pivot table

Tags: excel, excel-formula, range, pivot-table

I'd like to perform the standard deviation of a specific range in a pivot table.

I tried the following formula to get the SD of the range `C8:C28`:

```
=STDEV(GETPIVOTDATA("Sum of PL DIR & CAR",$A$4,"AssetClass2","Equity US"))
```

It returns `#DIV/0!`

Do you have the correct formula?

Here is the pivot table:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Based on your image, you **might** be able to use something like the below, assuming there is no data below the pivot table

This will work even if additional rows are added into the pivot, i.e making it a dynamic range with OFFSET etc.

```
=STDEV(OFFSET($C$8,0,0,COUNTA($C:$C)-2,1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use `INDEX` which is a non-volatile function:

```
=STDEV(INDEX($C:$C,ROW(C8)):INDEX($C:$C,COUNTA($C:$C)+1))
```

You may need to tweak that `COUNTA($C:$C)+1` to fit your criteria but this should give you the idea.